# match() returns array with two matches when I expect one match

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

Consider the following example:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str="filename.jpg";

var pattOne = new RegExp('\.[^\.]*$');
var pattTwo = new RegExp('(\.[^\.]*$)');
var pattThree = new RegExp('(\.[^\.]*$)', 'g');

document.write(str.match(pattOne));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(str.match(pattTwo));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(str.match(pattThree));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result:

```
.jpg
.jpg,.jpg
.jpg
```

I expect this result:

```
.jpg
.jpg
.jpg
```

Why placing parenthesis around the regular expression changes the result? Why using 'g' modifier changes again the result?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [`String.prototype.match` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression does not include the `g` flag, returns the same result as `regexp.exec(string)`.

Where the [`RegExp.prototype.exec` documentation *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) says:

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.

So as you introduced a capture group in the second expression, the first element is the whole match and the second contains the content of the capture group, which, in your example, is the whole match as well.
The first expression does not have a capture group, so you only get back the match.

Back to the `match` documentation:

> If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an Array containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns `null`.

With the `g` modifier, only matches are returned, but not the content of capture groups. In your string there is only one match.

Answer (score 10):

The `.match()` function returns an array. `document.write()` printed the array as a string.

When you captured a group in the string it makes an Array like this:

```
Array(
  [0] => 'the complete matched string',
  [1] => 'the first captured group',
  [2] => 'the second captured group', 
  [.] => '...'
)
```

So with your regex it becomes:

```
Array(
  [0] => '.jpg', // You match .jpg of the string
  [1] => '.jpg' // You captured the .jpg match
)
```

And if you print an array it places a `,` between the values.

Comment: the answer is correct, for clearness: capturing a group match happens because of the added parentheses. this is helpful  when you like to work on certain submatches. for example this would be possible: `var pattOne = new RegExp('\.([^\.]*)$');` than the group only contains the file-extension without the point.

Comment: I see some PHP poking through there