# Eloquent Javascript RegEx Example: Why Is Exec Returning A Two-Item Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm making my way through Eloquent Javascript's RegEx chapter (http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html) and I'm stuck on one of their examples:

```
var input = "A string with 3 numbers in it... 42 and 88.";
var number = /\b(\d+)\b/g;
var match;
while (match = number.exec(input))
  console.log("Found", match[1], "at", match.index);
// → Found 3 at 14
//   Found 42 at 33
//   Found 88 at 40
```

The RegEx itself is straightforward, but I thought it was odd that match[1] gave the correct string that was matched. So I changed it to `match[0]`, ran it, and got the exact same result.

So I changed the program to print out `match` as well, and sure enough, I get an array with the same value at index 0 and 1:

```
var input = "A string with 3 numbers in it... 42 and 88.";
var number = /\b(\d+)\b/g;
var match;
while (match = number.exec(input)){
  console.log("Found", match[1], "at", match.index);
  console.log(match);
}
// → Found 3 at 14
//   ["3", "3"]
//   Found 42 at 33
//   ["42", "42"]
//   Found 88 at 40
//   ["88", "88"]
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this result, and I don't see the purpose of pushing the matched text twice to the same array. It makes even less sense in light of their previous example:

```
var digit = /\d/g;
console.log(digit.exec("here it is: 1"));
// → ["1"]
console.log(digit.exec("and now: 1"));
// → null
```

What is going on here? Why does .exec return the value only once in an array sometimes and twice in an array at other times?

Comment: Because of the capturing group.

Comment: Actually, `RegExp#exec` is doing the same thing as `String#match` used with a regex without a global modifier. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002771/match-returns-array-with-two-matches-when-i-expect-one-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) will *always* return the matched string as the initial element in the array, any matched groups are then returned as the rest of the indeces.

Example:

```js
var regex1 = /abc/;

var regex2 = /a(b)c/;

var string = 'We always match "abc".';

console.log(regex1.exec(string));
console.log(regex2.exec(string));
```

So, both patterns match the same thing, but since in the second example there is group capturing `b`, it will be returned by `exec()`.

Comment: I see now. I just didn't fully understand what was being returned. Thank you very much!